# Bootstrap grid empty space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

While making a frontpage for my website, I stumbled across an annoying css problem. Look at the picture below:

[image]

Like shown in the picture, I want to list my items without the empty space. However, my attempts so far are unsuccessfull...

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- gets repeated for all items in array -->
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="flong in flongs">
                    <a href="/flong/id">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/350x175">
                                <p class="text-center"><b>Titel</b></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- end loop -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <div>
                <!-- gets repeated for all items in array -->
                <div class="row" ng-repeat="flong in flongs | limitTo: 5">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <a href="/flong/id">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/350x175">
                                    <p class="text-center"><b>Titel</b></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end loop -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

anyone any idea how to fix this? After messing with it for over 4 hours, I'm pretty tired with this shit ;P

On [8Flongs](http://8flongs.com) is an live example of the problem.

Thanks in advance!
Nick van der Meij

Comment: I've seen problems like this where a whitespace character (possibly a newline) in your html throws off bootstraps grid system. You can try to minify your html and see if that changes anything.

Comment: The boxes above the white space are not of equal size.  Can you include a link to the page source or the full html source code?  Also, I think you are using AngularJS to render the pages?  Probably should add that to your list of tags.

Comment: 8flongs.com. you can see a live example there

Comment: You want to put blue one to the left? but it placed in right? @BattleOn

Comment: I want it so that it there are no "whitespace-gaps" between the elements. So no matter how long it is, the space between articles is the same. They dont have to be horizontally correct, just vertical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with it for a few more hours i finally figured it out. Its not the most CPU friendly way, but here it is:

```
<div ng-hide="isLoading()">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div ng-repeat="flong in flongs">

                    <a href="/flong/{{flong.id}}" class="no-text-decorations" target="_blank" ng-show="$even" ng-mouseover="flong.showBody = true" ng-mouseout="flong.showBody = false">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/350x175">
                                <p class="text-center"><b>title</b></p>
                                <p class="text-center" style="color:white;" ng-show="flong.showBody">body</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div ng-repeat="flong in flongs">

                    <a href="/flong/{{flong.id}}" class="no-text-decorations" target="_blank" ng-show="$odd" ng-mouseover="flong.showBody = true" ng-mouseout="flong.showBody = false">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/350x175">
                                <p class="text-center"><b>title</b></p>
                                <p class="text-center" style="color:white;" ng-show="flong.showBody">body test</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Anyway, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I might be too late to solve the problem for BattleOn but I would suggest using salvattore library. It creates a pinterest like structure with fluid elements.

Site's here - http://salvattore.com/

Comment: I eventually solved it making a directive that splits the original array in 4 smaller arrays and then use those to make what i want ;) works flaweless

Comment: zenCoder, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: on 2021 the link has no library